# Generating an 80 MHz clock from a 100 MHz clock with VHDL in Spartan-7

Tags: vhdl, clock, spartan

I am new to VHDL and am targeting a Spartan-7 FPGA, using VHDL. For technical reasons I have to develop *outside* the Vivado or other environments. It seems like there are several posts that have similar questions, like [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121113/generating-40-mhz-clock-from-50-mhz) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/137114/generate-a-100-hz-clock-from-a-50-mhz-clock-in-verilog). The first one I can't quite understand and the second one seems to increase the clock frequency and use Verilog rather than VHDL.

I found [this](https://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2013/08/fractional-clock-division-dual-modulus.html) post but it seems that it is more of a practice exercise. Implementing it was hard to get right and the resulting clock, when it worked, looked imprecise and sort of jagged on the scope.

I also understand from various posts that there is something called a PLL (phase-locked loop) that will help and it is natively implemented on each chip with correspondingly chip-dependent VHDL implementations. I don't really understand how to find the documentation for PLL or if it's something I can access via "pure" VHDL, that is, *not* in an environment like Vivado.

So, the question boils down to: How can I get a reliable 80 MHz clock from a 100 MHz clock input on the Spartan-7 chip *without* using Vivado or some similar proprietary environment? Perhaps a sub-question is: How do I implement a PLL on Spartan-7 with pure VHDL?

Comment: You cannot. The PLL is hardware specific to the FPGA and therefore requires specific instructions outside of pure VHDL. Since clocking in general can't be reliably routed through generic logic, that means it is all hardware specific which means you need external ICs to adapt your clock signal. The only other, rather unreasonable alternative, is to reverse engineer how the the Spartan's bit stream works. This will let you do whatever you want outside of the designated development environment but obviously won't be pure VHDL.

Comment: You say you're working outside of ISE/Vivado, but does the tool chain you're using provide access to all the hardware primitives, including the DCMs and PLLs? If so, the documentation on how to use the primitives directly is very much available, but it is somewhat of a steep learning curve. I can help with that, but I need to better understand exactly what your constraints are.

Comment: I really wonder very much how do you plan to map and route the FPGA without their native tools? And yes, Spartan-7 does have dedicated tiles called "CMT", "Clock Management Tile", which let developers generate pretty much ANY clock. It contains all sort of multipliers for PLL and dividers, all with properly adjusted ranges for VCOs. Also the Xilinx tools have been under development by hundreds of fine engineers over many years, so your idea to bypass this process sounds blatantly implausible.

Comment: @Ale..chenski It has been done in evolutionary algorithm research where totally crazy things were implemented that would not be allowed by conventional design tools. This was not systematic design though. I don't know how closely the researchers were working to the bitstream though; Whether the algorithm was set loose with just ones and zeroes and had to learn the bitstream protocol on its own, or if it worked with higher level objects.

Comment: What are the specific requirements of the 80 MHz signal? Does it need to be symmetrical? How much jitter is allowed? For example, you can design something that "drops" every 5th clock of the 100 MHz input...

Comment: @DaveTweed the toolchain is very simple, because it is inside a (graphical) FPGA configuration tool provided by the manufacturer of my device (CAEN). The tool is OK when using the pre-defined blocks. But there is also an ability to make a "custom" block that uses pure VHDL. I am trying to implement this new clock in one of those.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I don't think I'm doing something as unreasonable as you think. I have a third-party environment where compiling the block diagram _does_ run Vivado to compile the final binary. It also allows "custom" blocks of VHDL. I guess the problem is that I don't know what that software does with the Vivado output and (if I designed the clock portion of the code in Vivado) how to include it back in the third-party compilation. I guess an alternative would be for me to bypass the third-party block diagrams and do Vivado only, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: @thebusybee I don't exactly know how much jitter is allowed but it's being used to encode FM digital communication to another device, so it doesn't seem like dropping every 5th pulse would be OK (that could be interpreted as the beginning of a transmission by the other device)

Comment: So you're using [Sci-Compiler](https://www.sci-compiler.com/user-guide/components/customcode/)? If it really is Vivado "under the hood", then I would expect that you should be able to use any of the hardware primitives in your code. You just won't have access to the Xilinx "wizards" that are normally used. And I guess that answers my other question about why you can't simply change the system clock to 80 MHz to begin with.

Comment: @DaveTweed yes, Sci-Compiler. We don't have access to the PLL primitive (or a lot of other ones) from within that environment. Support told us that we simply cannot get an 80 MHz clock. I'm trying to find a way around it because based on the output in the compilation step, the software is just directly running Vivado tools from the command line.

Comment: So maybe come at this from another direction. Given the nature of these boards, and what you've said so far, I presume you have some sort of DSP pipeline that needs to run at a sample rate of 80 MHz. (Why? Can't you just design it to work at 100 MHz?) With proper flow control (have you ever heard of AXI streaming protocol?), the pipeline clock can be any higher frequency (i.e., 100 MHz) and still process 80 MSPS data correctly.

Comment: @DaveTweed we are interfacing with another system that uses an 80 MHz clock for FM communication. Unfortunately, that system is difficult/impossible to change.

Comment: In that case, all I can say is that it seems you've picked the wrong hardware platform and toolchain for the job. Unless you can be a lot more specific about your application and its constraints, there's really no way anyone here can offer any concrete advice.

Comment: @DaveTweed that last comment wasn't necessary because it implies that I don't know my system. Like I said, there are constraints on my design, just like any design and I don't have control over many of them. I'm sure you'd do much better Dave.

Comment: So explain it to me. What part of *"we are interfacing with another system that uses an 80 MHz clock"* combined with  *"Support told us that we simply cannot get an 80 MHz clock"* am I failing to understand?